# Why is my Craft button labelled "Special"?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

I don't remember a message or notice accompanying the change.

After looking though my crafting options, nothing in particular seems "Special" either.

Is there a way I can make this go away?

[image]

Comment: I believe it's advertising the Tom Nook chair and KK Slider stool.

Answer (score 2):

The Special tag appears on this menu button while a limited-time offer is available. When you open the crafting menu, the third tab out of five (a leaf) is selected; select the second tab (a leaf within a 12-pointed star) to see these offers. If no offer is currently available, the Special tag will presumably be absent. (At the time of this posting, the offers are Tom Nook's chair and K.K. Slider's stoll, each available for 250 leaf tickets.)

As specified by Anthony in the comments below, the special tag will still show up even if you buy each of the items currently available.

Comment: Will this tag really be showing for 40 days? Is there a way to dismiss it?

Comment: The only possibility I can think of would be to spend 500 leaf tickets to buy both furniture items, but I cannot guarantee that would work as I haven't tried it. Anybody want to chime in with confirmation?

Comment: Bought both, special tag is still there.